# React: onClick method not working with parameters

Tags: reactjs

I have a 2d array of integers, each of which are being mapped to a render method that displays each value as a button. What I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the button, it updates the index of the elements, so it will show the updated value when the button is being rendered. However, the onClick method is never being called.

```
class Matrix extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: 0,
    cols: 0,
    elements: null
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.elements = this.createMatrix();
  }

  updateElements = (i, j) => {
    console.log("CLICK");
    const newElements = this.state.elements.slice();
    newElements[i][j]++;
    this.setState({ elements: newElements });
    console.log(this.state.elements[i][j]);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {Object(
              this.state.elements.map((e, i) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    {Object(
                      e.map((f, j) => {
                        return (
                          <td>
                            <MatrixElement
                              onClick={() => this.updateElements(i, j)}
                              value={f}
                            />
                          </td>
                        );
                      })
                    )}
                  </tr>
                );
              })
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
  createMatrix = () => {
    var matrix = [];
    var i, j;
    var sub;
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
      sub = [];
      for (j = 0; j < this.state.cols; j++) {
        sub[j] = 0;
      }
      matrix[i] = sub;
    }
    return matrix;
  };
}



class MatrixElement extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button>{this.props.value}</button>;
  }
}
```

If I change the onClick method to this:

```
onClick={this.updateElements(i, j)}
```

I get overflow errors. I imagine there is a much simpler way to implement what it is I'm trying to do, but I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide more code? A runnable/reproducible CodeSandbox would get you an answer very quickly.

Comment: onClick doesn’t receive I, j; it receives the synthetic event. You can’t make up parameters.

Comment: added more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely mean to not pass any parameters to the `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={() => this.updateElements(i, j)}
```

As you're relying on `i` and `j` from your iterators outside of that function.

**Edit**: You also need to handle the `onClick` in your Matrix element!

```
class MatrixElement extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.value}</button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: changed it to this but it still doesn't fire

Comment: Ah-ha, updated to make sure you're actually firing the click event!

Comment: Glad to hear it, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your `onClick` to accept two parameters, `i` and `j`, but React doesn't pass your variables to the function, it passes the [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). `i` and `j` are already in scope at that point of the code, so there's no reason to add extra parameters to your function.

Try changing your `onClick` to

```
() => this.updateElements(i, j)
```